# How Do Different Database Vendors Store Metadata Of Databases

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, oracle

I've been searching information about how access, MySQL, SQL Server and Oracle save the metadata of the databases, and I couldn't found it.

Comment: This is probably too broad for StackOverflow. However, at least for SQL Server (and I'm sure also for Oracle and DB2), there are some unleashed-style books that explain, among other things, the internal database structure. It's not simple because the metadata is spread out over a number of different places. For example, each row contains metadata about the columns in the row, there are page allocation pages, etc.

Comment: All information is in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables. This is the way JPA/nHIberntate and other ORM's generate the classes from there. MSSQL has specialised views for things such as replication as replication is not a SQL standard though most DB vendors implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrive MetaData of the table "database independent" using JDBC:

```
DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = connection.getMetaData();
```

You just need to add the connector (can be MySQL JDBC, SQL Server, SQLite, Oracle, Postgree, etc).